# Speed up Git Pushing/Pulling

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

Can anyone help me with Git Push/Pull Speed I have 6 MB/S connection but push and pull are at 40-45 KB/S its not all further i got

```
fatal: remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

It take hours to push. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are simply going to be limited by your download speed. Your best bet will be either getting someone geographically close to you to download it for you, or get someone to upload a copy of the repo to somewhere with a more reliable transfer such as a torrent. Good luck.

Also, 1 hour at 40kB/s is 140MB. That seems pretty large for most git repos... Make sure no one has accidentally uploaded a binary. (This happens more than you would expect)

Comment: Thanks for responding, actually i got something within.
Yes 140 MB/H is enough but my code was large 500 MB. I think you can understand my pain it breaked in between due to net loose and definitely  try to work with your saying the very next time i get chance.